# Como manter os dados de um html salvo

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Bem, eu preciso pegar os valor de uma textarea e enviar para uma segunda textarea na mesma pagina, mas quando eu der refresh não quero que o valor desda segunda textarea suma, como fazer isso usando javascript e Ajax?.

**Meu Codigo**

```
var textArea = getDOMElement("textarea", "class", "logarea", 0)
   var y = textArea.value;
   var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
   var t = document.createTextNode(y);
   x.appendChild(t);
   document.getElementsByClassName("span8 center")[0].appendChild(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o autoSave – A jQuery Plugin

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="idTextArea" placeholder="digite aqui ..."></textarea>

<script>  
/*
 jQuery autoSave v1.0.0 - 2013-04-05
 (c) 2013 Yang Zhao - geniuscarrier.com
 license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
(function(a){a.fn.autoSave=function(d,e){return this.each(function(){var b=0,c=a(this),f=e||1E3;c.keyup(function(){clearTimeout(b);var a=c.val();localStorage&&localStorage.setItem("autoSave",a);b=setTimeout(function(){d()},f)})})}})(jQuery);

var demoText = $("#idTextArea");


if (localStorage) {  
  var content = localStorage.getItem("autoSave");
  if (content) {
      demoText.text(content);
  }
}

</script>
```

[**Fonte**](http://geniuscarrier.com/autosave-a-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

**Cookies**

Cookies são dados, armazenados em pequenos arquivos de texto, no seu computador.

Quando um servidor da Web envia uma página da Web para um navegador, a conexão é encerrada e o servidor esquece tudo sobre o usuário.

Os cookies foram inventados para resolver o problema "como lembrar informações sobre o usuário":

Quando um usuário visita uma página da web, seu nome pode ser armazenado em um cookie.
Da próxima vez que o usuário visitar a página, o cookie "lembra" seu nome.
Os cookies são salvos em pares de nome e valor, como:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode salvar o valor da sua textArea na localStorage que é como se fosse um banco de dados do seu navgador.

```
localStorage.setItem('textArea', y);
```

Assim sempre que você carregar a página pode buscar o valor na localStorage e preencher no seu campo:

```
x.value = localStorage.getItem('textArea');
```

Comment: Bom tentei isso, mas mesmo apos limpar o 1 textArea o segundo tbm ficou vaziu

Comment: Isso depende da forma como você está salvando o valor do seu primeiro textArea, se você salvar o valor do mesmo na localStorage quando ele for vazio, o segundo tbm será.

Comment: coloquei um check de button, deu certo obg